# Is there a hash function for mapping two integers to one in an unique way?

Tags: algorithm, math, mapping

I want to map two integers A and B (A, B <= 10000) to an integer C with a function f such that
f(A, B) = f(B, A) and there are no two other integers E and F such that f(E, F) = f(A, B).

I originally tried using f(A, B) = 10001*A+B, but that didn't satisfy the requirement where f(A, B) = f(B, A).

Comment: Just do `f(A, B) = 10001*min(A,B)+max(A,B)`, assuming the integers are non-negative. This is however not  a question for StackOverflow, as it is pure mathematics.

Comment: @trincot: I can imagine that this is a question with a very practical application in programming, so I'd rather be inclined to say that it is very fitting for SO.

Comment: Every marhematical construct can have a nice application in programming. But the question here was not about programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. I assume that m,n are nonnegative integers. For n <= m put f(m,n) = 1/2 m(m+1) + n. For n > m put f(m,n) = f(n,m).

This assigns a unique integer to every (m,n), except that f(m,n) = f(n,m) for all m,n as desired (i.e. the operation is commutative). There is no need to assume that m,n <= 10000.

I wouldn't call this a hash function though. Such a function distributes elements evenly over a number of buckets, it doesn't typically assign a unique integer to each element.

Edit. The idea is to walk through all the nonnegative integral plane points lying on or below the line y = x. We start at the origin and walk north. When we reach the line y = x, we jump to (m+1,0). Then it's all a matter of counting the steps we have taken.

Comment: This seems pretty slick, perhaps you can explain why it works.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk All right, since you're president. See edit above.